# I can't figure out the reason for abnormal termination while executing levelOrder function?

Tags: c++, queue, binary-tree

This code is for Implementing binary tree.
It consist of insertNode(function which inserts node in the tree) and levelOrder(function which traverse the binary tree at level order).

insertNode function works fine but while executing levelOrder it successfully displays the data but after that it stops working and displays program has stopped working.

I can't find where i am going wrong?
Thanks in advance{ : )

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    int data;
}*root;

struct Queue
{

    Node *p[1000];
    int index=-1;

    Node *add(Node *ptr)
    {
        p[++index]=ptr;
        return ptr;
    }
    Node *peek()
    {
        if(index==-1)
            return NULL;

        return p[0];    
    }
    Node *pop()
    {
        if(index==-1)
            return NULL;

        Node *temp=p[0];

        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
            p[i]=p[i+1];

        index--;

        return temp;

    }
};

Node * createNode(int data)
{
    Node *p=new Node();
    p->data=data;
    p->left=p->right=NULL;

    return p;
}

///////Insertion Of Node////////

int insertNode(int val)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=createNode(val);
        return val;
    }

    bool found=false;
    Node *p;

    Queue q;
    q.add(root);
    while(found==false)
    {
        Node *l=(q.peek())->left;
        Node *r=(q.peek())->right;

        if(l==NULL)
        {
            (q.peek())->left=createNode(val);
            found=true;
            return val;
        }
        else
            q.add(l);

        if(r==NULL)
        {
            q.peek()->right=createNode(val);
            found=true;
            return val;
        }
        else
            q.add(r);


        q.pop();

    }
        return val;

}
/////////Traversal's///////////
void levelOrder(Node *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
        return;

    Queue q;
    q.add(p);

    while(true)
    {
        cout<<q.peek()->data<<" ";

        if(q.peek()->left!=NULL)
            q.add(q.peek()->left);

        if(q.peek()->right!=NULL)
            q.add(q.peek()->right);

        if(q.pop()==NULL)
            return;
    }

}


int main()
{
    root=NULL;

    insertNode(1);
    insertNode(2);
    insertNode(3);
    insertNode(4);

    levelOrder(root);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code before making this question?

Comment: yes I did.There is some bug in levelOrder function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have popped the last element from the queue, you `q.peek()->data` on the next iteration, when `q.peek()` is not a valid pointer.

Change your termination condition:

```
while (q.peek())
{
    cout<<q.peek()->data<<" "<< endl;;

    if(q.peek()->left!=NULL)
        q.add(q.peek()->left);

    if(q.peek()->right!=NULL)
        q.add(q.peek()->right);

    q.pop();
}
```

On a side note, this is one situation where a "loop-local" variable can improve readability - all those `peek`s add clutter:

```
while(Node *next = q.pop())
{
    cout<<next->data<<" "<< endl;;

    if(next->left != nullptr)
        q.add(next->left);

    if(next->right != nullptr)
        q.add(next->right);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo for finding the bug and also for improving the code.